# list Index error

Tags: python, list, indexing, web.py, error-list

- UPDATED -
  Hi i have "half" a problem with my web development:

I have this method in a class which takes a value from a database call, (the table in the database has a key: catId and another field)

```
def getCat(self):
        ''' devuelve el numero de la categoria
        '''
        a = self.datab.select('categorias',where='catName = $nombre', vars=dict(nombre=self.nombre))
        a= a.list()
        return a[0].catId

    context: i use this to make some categorization in my web content, so i want to return the value wich will join to the content table in the database.
```

So if i give to it a self.nombre wich is a string stored in a database row i'll ever take one element from the database.

The python interpreter gives me this error:

> ```
>   File "C:\xampp\htdocs\webpy\functions.py", line 26, in getCat
>     return a[0].catId
> IndexError: list index out of range
> ```
>
> > 127.0.0.1:51463 - - [05/Apr/2013 13:29:22] "HTTP/1.1 GET /c/\css\style.css" - 500 Internal Server Error

**but the web gives out the information correctly,**
I have no problem with the web output but i wish to know why is this error in the indexing a[0]

*I made the a.list() in order to simplify some uses of the itterbetter*

complete error mesage in the idle interpreter:

> ```
> 0.0 (1): SELECT catName FROM categorias ORDER BY catId ASC 
> 127.0.0.1:51900 - - [05/Apr/2013 16:46:31] "HTTP/1.1 GET /c/" - 200 OK
> 0.0 (1): SELECT * FROM categorias WHERE catName = '\\css\\style.css'
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\web\application.py", line 236, in process
>     return self.handle()
>   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\web\application.py", line 227, in handle
>     return self._delegate(fn, self.fvars, args)
>   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\web\application.py", line 409, in _delegate
>     return handle_class(cls)
>   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\web\application.py", line 384, in handle_class
>     return tocall(*args)
>   File "C:\xampp\htdocs\webpy\code.py", line 32, in GET
>     seleccion = functions.categoria(db,cat)
>   File "C:\xampp\htdocs\webpy\functions.py", line 16, in __init__
>     self.n = self.getCat() #calculo del numero de la categoria PROBLEMAS
>   File "C:\xampp\htdocs\webpy\functions.py", line 26, in getCat
>     return a[0].catId
> IndexError: list index out of range
> ```

Comment: Your question remains unclear. Could you please rephrase it?

Comment: I think I would write `vars=dict(nombre=self.nombre)` as `vars = {'nombre':self.nombre}`

Comment: thanks, i'll change the explanation.

Answer (score 3):

You need to do proper error handling, you can either do:

```
try:
    a[0].catId
except IndexError as ie:
    # Do some stuff here
except:
    # either re-raise the exception or pass it silently
```

Or you can do:

```
return a and a[0].catId or [] # This will check for empty list
```

It depends on your implementation choice.

Comment: ^^ now i'm implementing assuming correct uses, i keep that in mind to make try-except in advance to it

Answer (score 1):

That's the exact error message you would get if you tried to get an item from an empty list:

```
>>> [][0]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range
```

So it appears that `a.list()` is returning an empty list.

Comment: it's not an empty list, it has at least one element, I verified it. (commented before modification)

Comment: @user2209264 -- That's not possible.  You can only get an index error of this nature if the list is empty.

Comment: using the method in a test apart i have not the error mesage, but I do have if i calling it in the webpage.